# knowing if the key pressed was with caps lock on,detecting shift keys,function keys etc

Tags: c++, winapi

The following snippet prints the key pressed. But it doesn't tell me if the i printed an alphabet in capital letters.It doesn't detect the caps lock when i press it,doesn't detect the shift key or any other key like the function keys etc. How do i do that ?

```
  wchar_t buff[10];
  BYTE keyState[256] = {0};
  KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT * kbhook = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *) lParam;
  int result = ToUnicodeEx(   kbhook->vkCode,
                              kbhook->scanCode,
                              keyState,
                              buff,
                              10,
                              0,
                              NULL);


 wcout << result << endl;
```

Comment: Have you checked the state of `keyState`? [toUnicdeEx docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifically keyState variable.

Comment: That's because you pass a fake keyState instead of what you get from GetKeyboardState().  You are also ignoring my warning about the keyboard state being a process local property.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10719138/17034